# Finding a coefficient in a system, of linear equations in three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given that a system of equations does not have a unique solution.

$6x+ky+2z=a$

$6x-y-z=7$

$2x-3y+z=1$

I found one possible solution to be:

$(k+7)y=a-4$

The solution states that in any of the solutions, the coefficient of $x/y/z=0$ and therefore $k=-7$.  I am assuming that this is because there is no unique solution.  Why does this mean the  coefficient of $y=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $k+7\ne0$, then there is a unique solution for $y$, namely
$$y=\frac{a-4}{k+7}$$
Put that value for $y$ back into the equations, and you can calculate the unique value of $x$ and $z$.  That is a contradiction, because you know there is not a unique solution.
If $k+7=0$ the the first equation is $6x-7y+2z=a$.  But $\frac14Eq2+\frac94Eq3$ tells you that $6x-7y+2z=4$.  So if $a\ne4$, it is impossible for all three to be correct.  If $a=4$, then the first equation gives no new information.  Then you only have two equations.  $y$ can be anything, and you can solve equations 2 and 3 to find x and z.